# Why $var always return true?

Tags: php, if-statement

I just know `if(var)` is only work in condition `true` or `1` till now. But when I put something like variable `string` and other numbers like `12332` is also work .Is mean `if(var)`work in variable is `true or number or string` ?

```
<?php
  $Check  = "sosdjf";  echo : true
//$Check  = 12332;     echo : true
//$Check  = false;     echo : false
if($Check){
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "false";
}
```

we commonly check ,eg `if($Check == "sosdjf")` is do`if condition` ,but here `if($Check)` is aslo do `if condition` ! That's why ? It mean true ?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking here

Comment: do you need explanation?? Try using `$Check === true`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: we commonly check ,eg `if($Check == "sosdjf")` is do` if condition` ,but here `if($Check)` is aslo do `if condition` ! That's why ? It mean true ?

Comment: The docs link that @AlexBlex has posted tells you exactly what PHP considers false when you do a loose typed comparison as a boolean; anything else is considered true.... perhaps you should consider strict comparison checking

Comment: `""` and `"0"` are considered to be false in evaluation. Every other string expression evaluates to true. Use *identical operator* as @FrayneKonok already showed.

Comment: if($var) will go to the "then" branch for each value of $var evaluating to "true". Any non-empty string except from the string "0" evaluates to true, so it will pass. Same applies for any non-zero number.

Comment: `if ($check)` implies loose comparison to `true` and is a shortcut syntax for `if ($check == true)`

Answer (score 1):

So lets take a look at your code;

You assign `$check` to the value `sosdjf`

If we do a simple `if($check)` on the variable since the variable is set it will evaluate to `true`. This is because PHP is converting it to a `boolean` which will convert to `true` unless it meets the following criteria: [`an empty string or the string "0"`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

What you should really be doing is being explicit with your check

```
$check = 'someword';
if ($check === true) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'False';
}
```

The above would output `False` because `$check` is not a `boolean`, so it fails the strict type check as the two sides are not equal.

For clarification on Strings,

- Any empty `string` evaluates to `FALSE`
- Any non-empty `string` **that is not 0** evaluates to `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Return  True  When $Check is not NULL,NOT 0,NOT False,not "", not "0", not undefined (with a notice), not an empty array else it give you true

```
if($Check){
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: ...not "", not "0", not undefined (with a notice), not an empty array

Answer (score 0):

```
try this instead - 

in php 
$var = 123; //number
$var1 = "variable"; //string

here $var return true for both variables

if you want to check wether it is a numeric or string do this - 
$check = is_numeric($var); //it will return true

then return your desired output - 
if($check){
  echo "it is a number"; //true
}else{
  echo "it is a not number"; //false
}
```

Comment: `is_numeric` tests if the expression can be evaluated to a number. `is_numeric("123")` is `true`, while `gettype("123")` gives `"string"` and `gettype(123)` gives `"integer"`.

Comment: is_numeric("123") // true and is_numeric(123) //true - both will be true. if you will give like is_numeric("123test") //false because it is a string.

Comment: Check this: `var_dump(is_numeric("1e2"));
  var_dump(is_numeric(1e2));
  var_dump(is_numeric("0x1a2b3c"));
  var_dump(is_numeric(0x1a2b3c));
  var_dump(is_numeric("0b1"));
  var_dump(is_numeric(0b1));
  var_dump(is_numeric("012"));
  var_dump(is_numeric(012));
  var_dump("012" == 012);
  var_dump(intval("012") == 012);
  var_dump((int) "012" == 012);
  var_dump((float) "012" == 012);
  var_dump(floatval("012") == 012);
  
  var_dump(intval("0b1") );
  var_dump((int) "0b1" );
  var_dump(intval("0b1") == 0b1);
  var_dump(1 == 0b1); var_dump(010 == 8);`

Comment: We can say: `is_numeric` does nothing more than a check, if the given expression evaluates to a valid us-english decimal number format.

Comment: even `var_dump(010 == "08"); // true` funny? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something to the mix, see the `empty()` function:

```
var_dump(empty(false)); // true
var_dump(empty(null)); // true
var_dump(empty("")); // true
var_dump(empty(0)); // true
var_dump(empty("0")); // true
```

Comment: `var_dump(empty([]));  var_dump(empty($undefined_var));`